# Applescript list to file format error

Tags: applescript

Can somebody please explain me the technical structure of an AppleScript LIST saved in a text file? There must be a length (entries counter) somewhere inside.

I had a little crash and the saved file looks like corrupt now. It always shows 1800 entries instead of 2600 before. And there are for sure more than 1800 entries. I also think it cannot be like an EOF. If I make the file shorter than 1800 I get an EOF error. If I let it longer I get just 1800 entries.

How can I fix this problem? Where can I say inside the file: hey this list has 2600 entries.

```
# Read List
set fileName to choose file name with prompt "Please choose log file:"
set myPeople to read fileName as list
set listCount to length of myPeople
log "Count Start: "
log listCount
...
# Save List
set f to open for access fileName with write permission
write myPeople to f
close access f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Technically an **AppleScript** `list` written to a *disk file*, in the manner you have, does not produce a **text** *file*, even though you can open it in e.g. **TextEdit**, or in **Script Editor**! It's a **binary** *file* and when opened in **TextEdit**, or **Script Editor**, you'll not see the entire contents of the file.

You need to look at it in a **Hex Editor**, e.g. [**0xED**](http://www.suavetech.com/0xed/), and the first 4 *bytes* are `6C697374` or `list` and the second 4 *bytes* are the *number of items in the list*, e.g. `00000A28` is `2600` and `00000708` is `1800`.

That said, I'd restore the *file* from backup and not worry about how **AppleScript** writes a `list` to a *disk file* in the manner you have. I'd also make sure you maintain regular backups!

---

You can try changing the *value* of the second 4 *bytes*, but there is no guarantee it will recover the missing *list items*, as the *file* may also be corrupt in some manner or truncated. Backup the *file* before editing it in a **Hex Editor**!

Comment: thank you so much. this was really a GREAT help but alot of work :-). Now I think i understand it. there is a number of entries at the beginning of the file and also a lenght at the beginning of each list item. there was like 20 things corrupt in my file. but now it works fine again.

Comment: @donpasquale, Appreciate the thanks, however please have a look at: [What should I do when someone answers my question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers)